# How to listen to the signal of a view while having a QObject instance of it?

Tags: c++, qml, signals, qtquick2, qobject

I have created an attached object as described [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-definetypes.html#implementing-attached-objects-an-example).
This is my qml file in which I have used the attached object (`Constraint.widthInParent`):

```
 Window {
     id: root
     width: 640
     height: 480
     visible: true
     title: qsTr("Hello World")

     Rectangle {
         id: rect
         color: "black"
         height: width

         Constraint.widthInParent: 0.2
     }
}
```

In the above example, I have used the attached object in a Rectangle with the id `rect` and in this cpp file, I am getting the width of the Rectangle by using the QObject instance I have:

```
ConstraintAttached::ConstraintAttached(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent) {

    int viewWidth = parent->property("width").toInt();
}
```

Now I want to listen to the signals in this way...
My Rectangle has a signal that is `widthChanged` and now, I want to receive that signal through the `QObject` instance I have.
So, how can I listen to a view signal (e.g `widthChanged`) through a `QObject` instance?

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: Looks like a question clear enough which doesn't need a MRE to me. But I feel obligated to ask you why would you want to do that in C++ @Mahdi nezam parast ? This looks like very bad practice to me. Sorry for perpetrating the StackOverflow cliché about not answering the original question (:

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code where you obtain the pointer of ```myView```. It's also a good idea to provide a minimal code of ```myView```

Comment: @SoheilArmin I edited the question and explained it more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already have a valid pointer to a `QObject*` that lives inside the QML engine, you can simply do whatever you may do with any other `QObject`.

So, the short answer is :

```
connect(parent, SIGNAL(widthChanged()), this, SLOT(doSomething()));
```

This is the older signal/slot syntax where you use the `SIGNAL()` and `SLOT()` macros instead of passing function pointers or lambda functions.

But let's go further to get familiar with the Qt Meta Object system.
You can run this code on the `QObject*` you have in hand, to get more information about its functions. Let's assume that you still have the `QObject* parent`:

```
    auto methodCount = parent->metaObject()->methodCount();
    for(int i = 0 ; i<methodCount ; ++i){
        auto method = parent->metaObject()->method(i);
        qDebug() << method.methodSignature();
    }
```

This will list all methods of the `QObject* parent`. Read the documentation of [QMetaObject](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html) and [QMetaMethod](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetamethod.html), to see other possibilities. Actually the MOC, is generating a vast amount of information about a single `QObject` that is accessible runtime.

Good Luck